# Why don't we consider centripetal force while making FBD (free body diagram)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

> Consider a situation where a block is kept on a wedge which is further kept on a surface which rotates with $\omega$ the FBD for the same

[image]

My question is why dont we consider centripetal force in fbd? Is it because we are drawing it from a frame such that it cancels?

---

Edit :My simple definition of fbd tells me that it is a diagram representing all the forces acting on the body when viewed from  a particular frame which ensures that centripetal force must be acting only in a certain frame

Comment: From what frame are you analysing the problem?

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH The person has shown centrifugal force . Isn't it obvious that the frame is a non inertial one.

Comment: Yes, but it is not obvious which non-inertial frame. I see 2.

Comment: @OVERWOOTCH  umm I kinda have a doubt how would the fbd vary in two cases and in which frame will pseudo force act

Comment: @Anusha Direction of central force changes. When you have shown centrifugal force the block is at rest and when you are showing centrifugal force the block has radial acceleration.  So just the directon of central forces changes.

Comment: The FBD given in the image above is from a non-inertial frame i.e. the frame of the block, so a pseudo force, the centrifugal force $m\omega^{2}r$ is considered. And if you look at it from some inertial frame say the ground frame, you will have to consider the centripetal force which will have the same magnitude but opposite direction. TLDR : Centrifugal force (non-inertial frame i.e. block) is the pseudo force form of Centripetal force (inertial frame like ground)

Comment: Note that your accepted answer doesn't really answer your question...

Comment: @Anusha, "centripetal force" is a "catchall" phrase for any force that produces circular motion.  FBD's should show the actual force causing circular motion.

Comment: Everyone in this thread seems to know what FBD stands for. I count myself as pretty good at physics but I've never heard of the term. So I looked it up and - for the benefit of anyone else in the same position - it's a Free Body Diagram. Incidentally, surely there's a rule which states that a good StackExchange question should explain any abbreviations used, but I can't find such a thing so maybe not.

Comment: @AdamChalcraft It is listed as one of the tags, but it could be clearer.

Answer (score 6):

### From an inertial frame

You *are* considering the centripetal force. In fact you have already included it if you are using an inertial frame.

The centripetal force is not a new force. It is just a name we give to whichever force that pulls centripetally (towards the centre in circular motion).

In your case there is a component from the normal force which pulls centripetally (horizontally leftwards). So *that* is called the centripetal force.

### From the non-inertial frame

This above explanation is from an **inertial frame**, as if standing on the ground and watching the scenario. If you want to look at this from a **non-inertial frame**, by imagining that you are sitting on the block that is in rotation, which might be the case judging from your sketch, then from that frame the block doesn't seem to rotate. Rather it looks like the surroundings are "rotating".

Thus from that frame there seems to be no (resultant) centripetal force acting on the block. This means that the horizontal component of the normal force must be balanced out by something. That "something" is what we invent with the name **centrifugal force**, pointing opposite in the outwards direction.

This centrifugal force is a so-called pseudo-force in that it doesn't really "exist" - but we invent it mathematically in order to make Newton's laws hold true even in non-inertial frames.

Comment: First you say "In your case there is a component from the normal force which pulls centripetally", i.e. it is a real force. I think it is misleading to say "Thus from that frame there is no centripetal force acting on the block.", since the real force could not have vanished. I think it would be more accurate to say that in the non-inertial frame the block is stationary, thus the centripetal force must be balanced by something.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP My words are that from that frame there doesn't *seem* to be rotation and thus no centripetal force is observed. But I agree, the next sentence you mention could be interpreted a bit off, so I've made an edit. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3):

> My question is why dont we consider centripetal force in fbd ? Is it because we are drawing it from a frame such that it cancels?

Centripetal force and centrifugal force **never** act together. You are working in non-inertial frame and have shown centrifugal force , hence no need to show centripetal force.

---

I am attaching a picture from my notes to clarify what i meant so that my answer is interpreted correctly. The situation is quite similar to your question.

Consider a case of banking when viewed from 2 different frames :

[image: Inertial frame]

In ground frame , you don't show any centrifugal force.

[image: Inside Car]

From inside car, which is a non inertial frame ,$F_{centrifugal}$ is balanced by $Nsin\theta$.
No doubt $Nsin\theta$ will act in both frame , and is equal to $mv^2/r$ regardless of the frame but since car is at rest in non inertial frame , I wouldn't call it a centripetal force.

---

Edit 2 :

**Why would i call $Nsin\theta$ a centripetal force in the car's frame**

According to Wikipedia a centripetal force is defined as :  a force that makes a body follow a curved path.
Since the body is at rest in it's own frame , $Nsin\theta$ is  is not a cause of the centripetal force in the rotating frame.

Comment: Isnt centrifugal force a pseudo force? Which means it should be drawn in inertial frame

Comment: @Anusha  Pseudo Force acts in non inertial frame of reference .

Comment: This answer is misleading. Centripetal force doesnt “act” in any frame of reference. Centripetal “force” is merely a component of the net force that points towards the centre of curvature and is perpendicular to the  velocity at all times. It is akin to horizontal force or vertical force. Horizontal and vertical forces dont “act”; instead, forces like gravitation, electromagnetic, normal contact, friction etc... constitute a net force that HAS horizontal snd vertical components. In the same way, the net forces of objects in circular morion have centripetal components.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. Non-inertial frames don't make centripetal forces disappear.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Perhaps you misunderstood what i wanted to say. Please see my edit and correct me if i am still wrong.

Comment: Your first statement is still incorrect.

Comment: To clarify, in your diagrams $N \sin{\theta}$ is a centripetal force, which doesn't go away when we switch to a rotating frame of reference. Clearly, the centrifugal force and the centripetal force are both acting in this frame, hence the sentence "Centripetal force and centrifugal force never act together." is incorrect, as BioPhysicist pointed out.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Tbh , it just boils down to difference in terminology but still  this is where i disagree with BioPhyicist . Since in rotating frame the , the car is at rest , There is no centripetal acceleration and thus no centripetal force.

Comment: To LLlAMnYP, BioPhysicist and Bhavay, it depends on how you each define the word "centripetal force". Are we using that term for *any* force that is centripetal in direction or only for a resultant, total force. Bhavay is using the latter definition in the paragraph in question.

Comment: @Steeven I am defining centripetal force as is  Force which equal to vector sum of the all the forces which act towards center. Therefore $F_{c}=m\vec a$. But since in rotating frame a=0 , i don't think the car is centripetally accelerating.

Comment: @Bhavay Indeed. And sure, for $a=0$ in the rotating frame there is no vector sum resulting in a sideways, centripetal force. But the force that in an inertial frame would have caused centripetal acceleration is still present, and that's the point of the other commentor's.

Comment: @Steeven Exactly my point . In rotating frame $Nsin\theta$ doesn't provide the centripetal force .

Answer (score 3):

The reason we don't include the "centripetal force" in the FBD is the same reason we don't include the "vertical force" or the "horizontal force" in the FBD. Centripetal is just a direction, just like vertical and horizontal are directions. Just like how forces can be vertical or horizontal, forces can also be centripetal or tangential.

For example, including "centripetal force" on a FBD would just be like including the gravitational force as well as a second "vertical force" on the FBD for an object in free fall. In your case, there is a component of the force of the wedge on the block. This force points in the centripetal direction, so it is a centripetal force. But you wouldn't put an explicit "centripetal force" on the diagram; you already did that.

Comment: Ok this gives me another doubt that  centrifugal and centripetal are synonymous except for direction  but in the frame of wedge both must be experiencing centripetal as well as centrifugal force which means even centrifugal force shouldn't be included

Comment: @Anusha In a rotating frame you would include the centrifugal force on the FBD. It is an actual "force" in that case. "Centrifugal" in this case is not just a direction indicator (although I can see where the confusion lies, since technically centrifugal is a direction).

Answer (score 2):

> why dont we consider centripetal force in fbd ?

Indeed, we should include pseudo forces too, consider this :

[image]

Due to different position of wedge and block COM from rotational axis and they difference in mass- there will arise subtle tidal forces (differences in centrifugal forces of that within block and wedge). So in the end normal force upon block will be :

$$ N = mg \cdot \cos \alpha + m\,\omega^2r \cdot \sin\alpha - M\omega^2R 
\cdot \sin\alpha$$

Where $m$ block mass, $M$ - wedge mass, $r$ block distance from rotational axis, $R$ - wedge distance from rotational axis, $\omega$ - angular speed.

Answer (score 0):

The descriptions of circular motion often make it sound like centripetal and/or centrifugal force result from circular motion. But it's the opposite: circular motion results from centripetal force. There is nothing specifically exerting a centripetal force on the object. Centripetal force is an "output" force, not an "input" force. Gravity and the normal force are the "input" force; they are distinct forces from distinct physical sources. When we add those two forces together, we get the net force. Since this force is toward the center of the circle, it is a centripetal force. "Centripetal force" is just what we're calling the sum of all the input forces. It's not a force we start with when we're drawing the FBD, it's what we use the FBD to find.

Answer (score -2):

We do not consider the centripetal force to only be acting on the block, as it is also acting on the wedge. You have to consider the entire wedge-block system while calculating the centripetal force, so the centripetal force would act on the wedge-block system as a whole, not only on the block.

Edit:

Even if you do consider the centripetal force, then you have to consider a horizontal component of reaction from the wedge which correctly cancels out the centripetal force, so it won't make any difference.
I hope this helps!